# PHP to Display Categories based on parent

Tags: php

I have been fighting with this issue for about 2 months now and I still have not found a solution.

I am very new to PHP/MYSQL so please be easy / patient.

Basically, I have a page, called "browse.php" - This page has a query, which selects * from table and lists the categories AS A TREE.

What I actually need it to do, is **ONLY** list categories with a parent of "0".

When one of these categories are clicked, it should take you to a new page (lets call this page browse2.php) which then lists ONLY the categories for the parent of "CATID clicked on browse.php)

MYSQL DB:

```
    CREATE TABLE `categories_docs` (
    `CATID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `parent` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     PRIMARY KEY (`CATID`),
     UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
     ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

BROWSE.php:

```
   <?php

   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', '1');

   function display_children($parent) { 
       $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM categories_docs '. 
                        'WHERE parent="'.$parent.'";'); 
        // display each child 
        echo "<ul>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
            echo "<li class='child'><a href='browse2.php?cat=".$row['CATID']."'>".$row['name']."</a></li>"; 
        } 
        echo "</ul>";
    } 
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM categories_docs WHERE parent= 0'); 
    echo "<div id='cat_cont' >"; 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<div class='parent' align='left'><a href='ads.php?cat=".$row['CATID']."' >".$row['name']."</a></div>";
    }
    echo "</div>";

     ?>
```

I am really looking forward to one of you gurus being able to help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your query for the browse.php should be `select * from categories_docs WHERE parent=0`  this will bring out your parent categories then in your browse2.php you need to do `select * from categories_dcos WHERE parent=$incomingcategoryid` Where your `$incomingcategoryid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cat']);`

Comment: oh and stop using mysql_ use mysqli_ or PDO

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should really use PDO or mysqli commands, using mysql queries isn't really concidered 'good practice' nowadays.

As for your problem:
For getting your parent categories only:

```
SELECT * from categories_docs WHERE parent=0
```

In your 'sub'page:

```
SELECT * from categories_docs WHERE parent=$parentID
```